# Register Android user to my app by their device ID

Tags: php, android, authentication

I want to create an android app with authentication systems.There is a register activity with Name, email and password.When user give these and send data to my web server, the app automatically extract user's android device ID and save this in database on server.And When a user try to login and he/she gave name, email and password and click in LOGIN BUTTON, the app check name, email, password and also compare the device ID saved in database with these login information, to the device ID, the user is trying to login.If all these matches along with device ID, the user can log in.

Is it possible to do?

Please HELP me (:

Comment: So you want us to create a app for you and email you the apk ?

Comment: Nope.Is it possible to make like this?

Comment: I have successfully done this.

Answer (score 0):

Your login method will not perfect:
1. It is time consumable method of ligin (every time during login operation user have to insert user name, email and password)
2. Device id will also generate problem. What if user will try to login to his account using other device or user will change his mobile phone to new one.
3. You will loss a lot of time to prepare your own login method.

Please check Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App. Pleade start from:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: I want make them not to do this, use one account with multiple device.This is my main target..